# Calculating Probability based on Linear Regression in R or Excel

Tags: r, regression, modeling, linear, excel

Suppose we have a monthly budget of 1,000. For every day of the month we keep track of the total (cumulative) expenses. For example, let's say we are on 15th November and we have the following vector for these 15 days.

`cumulative_expenses <- c(100,120,140,170,230,240,260,260,260,300,350,430,440,460,470)`.

What I want is to calculate the probability of going over the budget of 1,000 in the end of the month.

I can predict the total expenses for the rest of the month using a linear regression model. But how could I calculate the probability of going over this budget, either in R or Excel?

In the end, I would like to have this probability for every day of the month, so that I know on each day in the range of the month (let's say from the 2nd day until the 29th) what is the probability of going over the budget.

Comment: Are all days equal or are there sundays, holdays, seasonal effects? Are all months equal or do we investigate each month on its own? Are there distributional assumptions about the expenses (are they normally or uniformely distributed) or are the first 15 values all we know?

Comment: @Bernhard The only seasonal effect we may have is the weekends, when we may have more expenses. We investigate each month separately. What would change if all months were equal? Also, what do you mean by equal? The first values are all we know.

Comment: The question here is, how much will you spend in the next 15 to 16 days and I was considering bootstrapping. If we all months were alike, we could bootstrap from all those days in all those months. If we investigate each month seperately we can only bootstrap from 15 values. I do not think it will be usefull to bootstrap weekend days seperately from working days as we only have 4 weekend days in our sample of size 15. Another question, will the money spend tomorrow depend on how much we spend today or is that independ?

Comment: No, it's independent. I will check out bootstraping, maybe there's something useful there.

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly, your OLS linear regression will be assuming that the true values of the target will be normally distributed around the predictions the regressor makes, with a variance of $\sigma ^{2}$. It just so happens, that you do not need to know the value of $\sigma ^{2}$ in order to find the optimal regression parameters.

People tend to say that the linear regression cost function is

$C = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_{i} - f(x_{i}; \theta))^{2}$

where $f(x; \theta)$ is your regressor function and $\theta$ are the parameters which you optimise your loss wrt.

The justification for this usually is that you are actually optimising the following cost function (known as the likelihood)

$C = \prod _{i=1}^{N} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma ^{2}}\left(y_{i} - f(x_{i};\theta)^{2}\right)}\right)$

It just so happens that if you find the $\theta$ which minimise the former, you will also maximise the latter.

To see this, take the logarithm of the latter and throw away constant terms to obtain:

$-\frac{N}{2}\ln \sigma^{2} - \frac{1}{2\sigma ^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_{i} - f(x_{i};\theta))^{2}$

so minimising the sum will maximise the logarithm of the original cost function and thus maximise the original cost function. Differentiating this and setting to zero, we find that

$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_{i} - f(x_{i};\theta))$

So to tie this all together:

1: Perform your linear regression as you would normally, to find your optimal $\theta$

2: Plug this optimal $\theta$ into $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_{i} - f(x_{i};\theta))$ to calculate your optimal $\sigma ^{2}$

3: You wanted to know your probability of going over budget at the end of the month. Firstly make your prediction for the end of the month, using the regressor. Let's say it says "the single most likely value is that you'll be at 750". Now let's say that at stage 2 you calculated to $\sigma^{2}=10,000$ and thus $\sigma=100$. Well going over 1000 would correspond to a Z-score of (250)/100=2.5, so you can now consult your z-table and you'd fine a 0.0062% chance.

I'd just add that this is a so-called maximum likelihood approach. There are more principled/complex approaches for approaching problems like this called Bayesian approaches, but this is probably a good place to start.

Comment: What variables are you proposing to regress here and how do you justify supposing the relationship they exhibit during the first half of the month will continue through the second half??

Comment: I think that's a question for the original poster. My answer applies to linear regression in general. Reading through the original post again, it's not clear whether there is/are covariate(s) and this is indeed regression, or just extrapolation. Perhaps the dependent variable is a discretised time variable and linear growth is assumed?

Comment: Yes, we want to calculate this probability assuming that we will continue to have linear growth. Can I ask something more, using this method do you take into consideration that the cumulative expenses will only increase (or at least stay steady) ? Let's say that on day 15 I have an observation of 740 and on day 30 I have a prediction of 750. The probability of having a true value smaller than 740 on day 30 should be zero.

Comment: So if the y variable is cumulative cost, this means, for example, that $y_{t+1} \geq y_{t}$, and thus the "normally distributed errors" assumption doesn't apply. I think you actually want to do your linear regression on the daily spend. A linear regression might be overkill, or the daily spend might not be a function of time, you might find it easiest to just fit a Gaussian on daily spend, and then simulate lots of months, add up the spends, and see how often spend exceeds 1000 (alternately, this problem is also analytically tractable)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Gaussian fit you referred to?

Comment: If you find that the expenses on any given day appear to be normally distributed, then you could fit a Gaussian to this. The sum of a bunch of independent (bit of an assumption I know) normally distributed variables is also normally distributed. If you find your daily expenses are normally distributed with $\mu=40$ and $\sigma=30$, then the distribution of expenses in the remaining 15 days in November will be normally distributed with $\mu=600$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{15}\cdot 30$, from which you can calculate the probability it will exceed 530, and thus your total expenses exceed 1000